# Assign html <a> tag to a textarea value

Tags: javascript

I need to assign an `<a>` tag to a textarea value, separated with a comma. I'm trying to insert email IDs I get from a response of an ajax request. How do I achieve this using JS?

I tried using:

```
$('reminder_email').value += "<a href='#' id='+id'>+email+</a>";
```

Comment: You should add some more code and clarify what you're going for.

Comment: I am trying to insert the email as link as value of textarea

Comment: `<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">` Like this???

Comment: sorry for pasting wrong code I tried.. THis one is what I have tried.. $('reminder_email').value += '<a href='#' id='+id'>+email+</a>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'reminder_email' is the `id` of the relevant `textarea`, and that the response is an array of emails:

```
var emailAddressesArray = ['emailAddress@host.tld', 'emailAddress2@otherHost.tld'];
$('#reminder_email').val(emailAddressesArray.join(', '));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/neEQA/).

If, on the other hand, you're trying to create the HTML of an `a` element with a `mailto` protocol (for copying/pasting elsewhere):

```
var email = 'emailAddress@host.tld';
$('#reminder_email').val('<a href="mailto:' + email + '">' + email + '</a>');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/neEQA/1/).

Note that you can't create clickable links within a `textarea`, as they can't contain HTML (*just* text).

If, though, you have an object from which to create your value:

```
var email = [{
    'address': 'emailAddress@host.tld',
        'id': 'emailOne',
        'text': 'UserNameOne'
}, {
    'address': 'anotherAddress@host2.tld',
        'id': 'emailTwo',
        'text': 'UserNameTwo'
}];
$('#reminder_email').val(function(_, v){
    for (var i = 0, len = email.length; i < len; i++){
        v += '<a href="mailto:' + email[i].address + '" id="' + email[i].id + '">' + email[i].text + '</a>, ';
    }
    return v.slice(0, v.length - 2);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/neEQA/6/).

The reason your code:

```
$('reminder_email').value += '<a href='#' id='+id'>+email+</a>;
```

didn't work is twofold:

1. `$('reminder_email')` is a selector looking for `reminder_email` tags (which don't exist); assuming that it's an `id` you're looking for you'll need to use: `$('#reminder_email')` instead,
2. A jQuery object/collection has no `.value` property, instead use the `val()` method (without arguments to *get* the current value, or with an argument to *set* a new value).

Comment: Oh.. You are correct David...As you said, the textarea will contain only text and cannot be clickable.. I would like to appear as links.. But since it is inside a form and when submitted I need to grab these email ids as params. So any thoughts on the solution for that...??

Comment: Can you show what you're working with? What (relevant) variables and HTML? I'm having to guess a lot of what's going on, and guesses don't, typically, make for great, or even good, answers.

Comment: I have a form where I have an input field and a textarea... I have another div container which contains all the email ids with add and remove links.. So when an email id is clicked inside the div container, that email id should be added in the rails form.. And when the form is submitted, I get the params of email in controller and send a mail to that email id..

Comment: Previously I was trying to insert only the email ids(as text) seperated with commas.. Like abc@gmail.com,aaa@gmail.com etc.. But there was no problem in that... But when I click on remove link from that container, I need to remove it simultaneously from the forms email field also... If that is possible then it would do

Answer (score 0):

hoping you have jquery imported, try this:

```
$('reminder_email').val("<a href='#' id='"+id+"'>" + email + "</a>");
```

are you appending it? why do you use `+=` ?